# Ember: Set default value to bs-form-element

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How to set the default value of `{{bs-form-element controlType="date" property="model.orderDate"}}`
I am unable to bind it properly.

Comment: Does `property="model.orderDate"` work? Is the value visible if you change the `controlType` to `text`?

Comment: Remove the quotes `"model.orderDate"` refers to a string, `model.orderDate` refers to the property.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Got it working, the problem is data itself.

Comment: You should post it as an answer and accept it. :)